# How to run SparkApplication using `spark-kubernetes-operator` multiple times

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, kubernetes-operator, google-spark-operator

I am planning on using `spark-kubernetes-operator` (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) for managing my spark applications. I have managed to install and get the basic examples working on local k8s setup.

I have created a sample `SparkApplication` using `kubectl apply -f <file>.yaml`. Now this application has executed and driver is in the `Completed` state.

If I want to rerun the job again, do I need to resubmit the app with same yaml like `kubectl apply -f <file>.yaml` ?

Is there any other way to rerun it again?